# I want to remove this strange characters before XML tags?

Tags: java, xml, jdbc, netbeans, domparser

str1 >> ��

I want to remove this strange characters before XML tags ??

```
byte [] bytes = rset.getBytes("CONTENTS");
     String str1 = new String(bytes);

System.out.println("str1 >> "+str1);
```

Comment: I select from oracle Db and carry execution query in result set  'rset'

Comment: What is in your DB? It is contains unvanted symbols?

Comment: select from table which contains full XML file in each row

Comment: Since it's two bytes, maybe they are just the BOM for encoded Unicode text.

Comment: It is look like encoding problem. You need to create string puting right encoding as second parameter to `String` constructor.

Comment: Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(str1.getBytes("utf-8_BOM"))));

Answer (score 1):

That code is in fact using the default platform encoding.
So the software is dependent on the current OS encoding.
It should be the encoding of the stored bytes.

```
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
byte[] bytes = rset.getBytes("CONTENTS");
String str1 = new String(bytes, charset);
```

And then those two strange characters *just might* be a single character, the BOM, a zero-width space uses as UTF-8/UTF-16 marker, and absolute redundant:

```
str1 = str1.replaceFirst("^\uFEFF", "");
```

This removes the BOM, U+FEFF, from the begin (`^`) of the text.

When editing the XML ensure to save it as UTF-8 **without** BOM.

---

Or it might be Left-To-Right, Right-To-Left chars:

```
str1 = str1.replaceAll("(?u)[\u200E\u200F]", "");
```

This might prove too drastic.

Comment: thanks for replay but it doesn't work, I still have strange characters before XML tags

Comment: str1 >> �� <?xml version="1.0"?><!--MRM Generated XML Output on

Comment: Dump the chars (java8): `str1.toCodePoints().forEach(cp -> { if (cp < 32 || cp > 126) System.out.println(cp); });`

Comment: sorry nut i can't understand what u mean !!

Comment: Added another idea to the answer: that it might be Right-To-Left/Left-To-Right controls. My comment intended to give code to dump special Unicode, but it needs java 8.

Comment: @AhmedElgrouney but better check that inside mixed latin/arabic script there is no problem introduced. There might be a better matching say with `<`.

Comment: Thank you very much